# Beacons aren't showing Altbeacon

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, altbeacon, eddystone

I'm trying to get the code working with the demo code provided by [Altbeacon](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html). Normally it should log something but it doesn't. What it does show in logcat is this

```
01-11 20:50:33.964 12498-12508/com.example.thomas.test1 D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScanResult() - ScanResult{mDevice=EF:47:2A:56:1B:55, mScanRecord=ScanRecord [mAdvertiseFlags=6, mServiceUuids=[0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb], mManufacturerSpecificData={29540=[5, -86, -69, -52, -35, -18, -1, 0, 17, 34, 51, 68]}, mServiceData={0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb=[16, -30, 0, 103, 111, 111, 103, 108, 101, 0]}, mTxPowerLevel=-30, mDeviceName=Beacon1], mRssi=-26, mTimestampNanos=981220542678629}
```

So it does detect the beacon but does not show it as a log.

Code i used:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer{

```
protected static final String TAG = "RangingActivity";
private BeaconManager beaconManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

    beaconManager.bind(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    beaconManager.unbind(this);
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "The first beacon I see is about "+beacons.iterator().next().getDistance()+" meters away.");
            }
        }
    });
    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what i did wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

1. You need to add beacon parsers for the Eddystone frames you want to detect into the onCreate method.

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
     beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
       setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
     beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
       setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT));
     beaconManager.bind(this);
   }
   ```
2. Make sure you have requested the proper permissions dynamically, which is required if you are on Android 6+.  Instructions for doing this are here: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html
3. Add a log line to the start of `onBeaconServiceConnect()` to make sure that is getting called.

Comment: Thanks it works now with my phone, but when i want to run the app with a phone of a friend it says: BluetoothLeScanner: could not find callback wrapper. Any idea what would cause this?

Comment: He has android 7.0 and my phone has android 5.5

Comment: Android 5.5 does not require dynamic location permissions as described in point 2.  Android 7 does.  That is probably the difference.  Read the link on point 2.

Comment: Thanks this helped, can u help me one more time? I want to write the rssi values to a database, the code to write works but when i want to write the data to the database the app crashes. Could it be that the combination of scanning beacons and writing something else could cause a problem? Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I do not think the crash has anything to do with scanning, it probably has to do with writing to the database if it started crashing after you added that code.  I suggest you post a new question showing a code snippet including line indicated by the top of the stack trace.